# Can anyone explain why Drupal Answers attracts more spam than any other SE site?

Tags: discussion, support

I am dying to know it. Maybe something in its name or logo...

Comment: You might to share how you came to this analysis...

Comment: @Pat The most spam the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) reports to chat come from drupal.

Comment: @nicael Do you have any empirical data to back that up? I doubt you (or anyone) has seen every chatbot report that's ever been posted. how are you discounting the possibility that you and the DA spammers just share the same waking hours, for example?

Comment: @Clive I've seen pretty close to every report, and I can tell you that Drupal leads the pack by a significant margin, trailed by Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Undo Thanks, that's interesting to know

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=drupal&Room=89&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to ask the people who are choosing which sites to spam for their motivation, to get any sort of realistic answer.

We can't tell you here, unfortunately, we simply don't know who these spammers are, never mind why they may or may not choose to spam one site over another.

Maybe they like blue things. Maybe they like things starting with the letter 'D'. Who knows :)

Comment: "You would need to ask the people who are choosing which sites to spam for their motivation". Lol. I guess he posted at the wrong place then...